# How to escape square brackets in racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to parse some function to (let([x 1]) x) but racket read [ as (. Is there any simple way that I can keep it []?

this is what returns when I try to escape with backslash[ backslash]:

```
    (let (|[| fact #f |]| |[| fact2 #f |]| |[| fact3 #f |]|) fact3)
```

what I want is:

```
,   (let ([fact #f][fact2 #f][fact3 #f]) fact3)
```

Comment: nevermind, I figured out I don't need this.

Comment: you should probably delete the question, then…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [read-syntax](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-syntax%29%29) primitive, then the parentheses within the parsed data structure have a [paren-shape](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28idx._%28gentag._30._%28lib._scribblings/reference/reference..scrbl%29%29%29) property that will tell you if they were square or not.

For example:

```
> (define stx-1 (read-syntax #f (open-input-string "(hello)")))
> (define stx-2 (read-syntax #f (open-input-string "[hello]")))
> stx-1
#<syntax::1 (hello)>
> stx-2
#<syntax::1 (hello)>
> (syntax-property stx-1 'paren-shape)
#f
> (syntax-property stx-2 'paren-shape)
#\[
```

So the [syntax](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html) data structure can remember that the square brackets are there.